# How to implement a java class using generics that does not cause "uses unchecked or unsafe operations" warning

Tags: java, generics

I was trying to implement some example classes that use generics and I noticed that there is a part of my code highlighted with the following warning:

> Information:java: SomethingAbstract.java uses unchecked or unsafe
>   operations.

This is happening on this piece of code `converter.convert(this)`.

I suspect the problem is actually on the return type of my ConverterFactory.getConverter(...). I tried to change it's return to Converter and then I get

> Error:(6, 20) java: incompatible types: org.test.AtoBConverter cannot
>   be converted to org.test.Converter

I tried looking at the AtoBConverter or BtoAConverter to see how to change them, but wasn't able to figure it out.

What should I add/change in order for the warning to disappear?

Here are my example classes:

```
public interface Something {
    <R extends Something> R convertTo(Class<R> to);
}

public class SomethingAbstract implements Something {
    @Override
    public <R extends Something> R convertTo(Class<R> to) {
        Converter converter = ConverterFactory.getConverter(this.getClass(), to);
        return to.cast(converter.convert(this)); // <<< warning on this line
    }
}

public class SomethingA  extends SomethingAbstract {}

public class SomethingB extends SomethingAbstract {}
```

And then the classes that do some work with the `Something` types:

```
// Convert T to R
public interface Converter<T extends Something, R extends Something> {
    R convert(T toConvert);
}

public class AtoBConverter implements Converter<SomethingA, SomethingB> {
    @Override
    public SomethingB convert(SomethingA toConvert) {
        SomethingB somethingB = new SomethingB();
        // Do some stuff to convert
        return somethingB;
    }
}

public class BtoAConverter implements Converter<SomethingB, SomethingA> {
    @Override
    public SomethingA convert(SomethingB toConvert) {
        SomethingA somethingA = new SomethingA();
        // Do some stuff to convert
        return somethingA;
    }
}
```

And the factory that is used to get the right converter:

```
public class ConverterFactory {
        public static <T extends Something, R extends Something> Converter getConverter(Class<T> from, Class<R> to) {
            if (from.equals(SomethingA.class) && to.equals(SomethingB.class)) {
                return new AtoBConverter();
            } else if (from.equals(SomethingB.class) && to.equals(SomethingA.class)) {
                return new BtoAConverter();
            }
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No converter found to convert from " + from + " to" + to);
        }
    }
```

In the end, this is meant to be used like this:

```
SomethingA a = new SomethingA();
SomethingB b = a.convertTo(SomethingB.class);
```

Comment: In your `ConverterFactory` you should have `public static <T extends Something, R extends Something> Converter<T,R> getConverter(Class<T> from, Class<R> to)`

Comment: @biziclop, true, but it's not the only thing.

Comment: @kocko Yes, I'm just working my way through the code.

Comment: Can't you use copy constructors instead? `SomethingB b = new SomethingB(a);`?

Comment: The key problem seems to be this line: `Converter converter = ConverterFactory.getConverter(this.getClass(), to);` There's no way to reformulate this in a way that would pick up the actual class as the `T` type parameter of `converter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Converter` interface is generic, so the return-type of the `ConverterFactory#getConverter()` should be generic, too.

The real problem there is another, though:

- `AtoBConverter extends Converter<SomethingA, SomethingB>`
- `BtoAConverter extends Converter<SomethingB, SomethingA>`

Even though these two types both extend `Converter`, they don't extend the same superclass at Runtime, because (for example) `AtoBConverter` will expose a method with a signature `SomethingA convert(SomethingB toConvert)`, while the other one will expose a method with a signature `SomethingB convert(SomethingA toConvert)`. This, however, is detected by the compiler and it correctly raises an error, because `AtoBConverter` and `BtoAConverter` cannot be produced by the `getConverter` method. The only possible return type that matches both of them is `Converter<?, ?>`, but I don't think it's suitable in your case.

However, there's an easy workaround for this - you can just introduce two separate methods in the factory class, which produce `AtoBConverter` and `BtoAConverter`:

```
public class ConverterFactory {

    public static AtoBConverter getAToBConverter() {        
        return new AtoBConverter();
    }

    public static BtoAConverter getBToAConverter() {        
        return new BtoAConverter();
    }

}
```

Then, I believe that `SomethingA` and `SomethingB` **should not be** responsible for converting themselves into something else - this should be what the converter does and that's why I find the `Something#convertTo()` method redundant (as well as the `SomethingAbstract` class).

In the end, you will be able to do:

```
SomethingA a = new SomethingA();
AtoBConverter converter = ConverterFactory.getAToBConverter();
SomethingB b = converter.convert(a);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Now I understand better this part in the generics tutorial [Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).
My idea with the Converters is that if in the future I had more, I would like to retrieve them from the factory automatically without having to call a specific method.